# ¿Cómo puedo esperar hasta que una tarea Asincrona se termine de ejecutar?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Esta parte de codigo

```
public List<RutaArco> generatePreOptimalRoute() throws InterruptedException {
    List<RutaArco> aux = new ArrayList<>();
    Toast.makeText(this,"ForceBrute=not done yet",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    for (int i= 0;i<Points.size();i++)
    {
        for (int j= 0; j < Points.size(); j++) {

        if(i!=j) {
            String starter = String.valueOf(Points.get(i).latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(Points.get(i).longitude);
            String ender = String.valueOf(Points.get(j).latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(Points.get(j).longitude);
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" + starter + "&destinations=" + ender + "&mode=driving&language=fr-FR&avoid=tolls&key=" + R.string.API_MATRIX_KEY;

            GeoTask a = (GeoTask) new GeoTask(MapActivity.this).execute(url);




            aux.add(new RutaArco(Points.get(i), Points.get(j), temporaloptimaldistance, temporaloptimaltime));
            temporaloptimaltime = "";
            temporaloptimaldistance = 0.0;




        }

    }
    }
 Toast.makeText(this,"ForceBrute=Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return aux;
}
```

Exactamente en la parte de la ejecucion del Geotask la cual esa es la tarea asyncrona,necesito que se ejecute y se termine de ejecutar para realizar la siguiente llamada a la linea de codigo, porque tnego que almacenar los resultados en una lista. Como puedo hacer para que se quede esperando hasta que se complete la tarea?

Comment: No tienes que usar otra library, la misma clase AsynckTask tiene el método get() para este proposito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En android para esperar el resultado de una tarea asincrona, usando un Asynctask y continuar se raliza mediante el método [**get()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()), para obtener el valor obtenido en `onPostExecute()`, ejemplo:

```
  String resultadoAsynctask =  new MyAsyncTask().execute().get();
```

Debes tomar en cuenta que el proceso esperara hasta obtener el resultado del AsyncTask, esto por el uso de [**get()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()):

> [**get()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()) Espera si es necesario para que se complete el cálculo,
>   y luego recupera su resultado.

---

En tu código sería:

```
  GeoTask a = (GeoTask) new GeoTask(MapActivity.this).execute(url).get();
```

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Esta respuesta, me funciono muchas gracias, solo que el get me devolvia un string asi que lo iguale a uno

Comment: No necesitas realizar todo esto: GeoTask a = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
     return new GeoTask(MapActivity.this).execute(url);
}).get(); simplemente llamar .get() para esperar obtener el valor. @DiegoAlejandroUribeBlatnik

Answer (score 1):

Para ello tienes que usar la libreria CompletableFuture de Java (solo disponible en JDK 8 y 9). El codigo sería el siguiente:

```
GeoTask a = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
     return new GeoTask(MapActivity.this).execute(url);
}).get();
```

Será necesario manejar las excepciones lanzadas con try,catch acomoda tu implementación del codigo a esos errores, siguiendo la hipotesis de que una excepción es un fallo en la recogida del dato.

Comment: Intente el codigo, como lo pusiste y me salta unos errores, lo modifique de esta manera pero me sale missing return statement

Comment: Arreglado prueba esto, es coherente que no te funcionara, lo puse sin probarlo y no me acordaba al 100% de como funcionaba...